Calling REST API causes to crash emulator
I'm trying to import a simple data from my WordPress site rest API in Flutter.
When I run the app on Chrome there is no problem and everything goes well.
When I run it on my Android emulator it crashes and stops working! Why is this? I'm a beginner in this subject.
Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
  var basicAuth = 'Basic *****';
  var response = await http.get(
      Uri.https('myrestapii.liara.run', 'wp-json/wp/v2/posts/6'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Authorization': basicAuth,
        'Content-Type': 'apllication/json; charset=UTF-8'
      });
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Post.fromjson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('failed to load post!');
  }
}

I want it to work on the emulator as well.
I have no idea why this problem occurs.
in debug console i saw this. i think it's the crash log if i'm not wrong:
E/flutter (11014): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: ClientException with SocketException: Read failed (OS Error: Software caused connection abort, errno = 103), address = myrestapii.liara.run, port = 44938, uri=https://myrestapii.liara.run/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/6
E/flutter (11014): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:119:7)
E/flutter (11014): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11014): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:32)
E/flutter (11014): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11014): #2      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:12)
E/flutter (11014): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11014): #3      fetchPost (package:project7wpapi/api/myapi.dart:7:18)
E/flutter (11014): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11014): 
E/flutter (11014): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: ClientException with SocketException: Read failed (OS Error: Software caused connection abort, errno = 103), address = myrestapii.liara.run, port = 44936, uri=https://myrestapii.liara.run/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
E/flutter (11014): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:119:7)
E/flutter (11014): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11014): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:32)
E/flutter (11014): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11014): #2      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:12)
E/flutter (11014): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11014): #3      fetchAllPosts (package:project7wpapi/api/myapi.dart:22:18)
E/flutter (11014): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11014):

F/crash_dump32(11545): crash_dump.cpp:474] failed to attach to thread 182: Permission denied
" it's like the app freezed"

Add the crash log too, to your question.

i edited my question . pls take a look at it ... i'm really stugling with this problem

If you encounter a network error, ensure to wrap your network request in a try-catch block to handle potential errors

so whats the point of tru catch when  still its going to have the error?
